# Why use "this.props.dispatch" rather than "store.dispatch" directly in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Is there any detriment to directly using store.dispatch?

It seems to me it's much easier to call (since it's available to all child components) and in my testing so far, I've yet to find a difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In [universal apps](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html), you'll want a different store instance on every request. If you just export store as a singleton from some module, you'll have a hard time adding server rendering.

This is why we never encourage singleton store in the docs, and always encourage you to use [`<Provider>`](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store) to pass it down the hierarchy via React [context](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html). This makes store available to the consuming components without making it a singleton.

As for why [`connect()`](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) from React Redux passes `dispatch` as a prop instead of `store` itself—it's because you don't really need `store` itself in the connected components. Subscription and reading state is done by `connect()` so you'll only ever need `dispatch()` in components.

Comment: How do you access the store from an action creator, for example, if it's not a singleton?  I was thinking about having a store module that exports a singleton and a factory for client-side and server-side use, respectively.

Comment: @orourkedd Why do you want access to the store in action creators?

Comment: I've been thinking about it and now believe it's a bad pattern to access the store in action creators or in any other global/singleton manner.

Answer (score 2):

Usually I find that the store is initialized in a top level module, and then used in lower level modules by the [react-redux](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md#quick-start) connect function.

This prevents the need to import the store directly in a lower level module, as it would be importing from the top level.